# Serializing a javascript array with Jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, serialization

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var checksSinceLastPostBack = new Array();

function clientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
    var ajaxManager = $find("<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ClientID %>");
    var serializedCheckData = checksSinceLastPostBack.serializeArray();

    if (ajaxManager != null)
        ajaxManager.ajaxRequest(serializedCheckData);
}
</script>
```

The

```
var serializedCheckData = checksSinceLastPostBack.serializeArray();
```

doesn't seem to work. Am I misunderstanding this?

Also if this works, how would I deserialize it in the code behind?

**EDIT**: Sorry, this is in ASP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) is for serializing form elements with name/value pairs, not a normal [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).  To convert *that* to a string you want something like:

```
var serializedCheckData = checksSinceLastPostBack.join(',');
```

...or some other delimiter.  If you have more complex data you may want to go a JSON route.

Comment: The [ **MDC reference for `.join()`** ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)